# Android Studio App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, apk

Всем привет. Написал я в общем программу(простенький мессенджер). Запустил на эмуляторе все норм, работает(версия на эмуляторе 7.1.1). Решил я про тестить на своем андроиде(версия андроида 6.0.1) ничего не работает, вылетает программа и пишет Unfortunately app has stopped. Заходил я такое на андроид монитор смотрел ошибки, все чисто никаких ошибок. Пытался я менять sdk версию в build.gradle но это не помогает все тоже самое. Устанавливал я apk-debug на свой андроид для тестирования.  Как мне это исправить? За ранее спасибо.

Вот мой build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lado.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets{
        main{
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.liuguangqiang.swipeback:library:1.0.2@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: исключение во-первых скиньте. Код из build.gradle информацию не несёт.

Comment: @pavel а где находится исключение? Просто я первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь

Comment: @pavel в logcat там где error ничего нету там пусто

Comment: на устройство, на котором не происходит отладка нужно ставить релизную версию, а не отладочную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все заработало. Что бы такой проблемы не было нужно зайти File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment ->Instant Run -> uncheck "Enable instant run". Просто отключить Instant Run.